# Getting specific value of a key from child of child data in Firebase with Swift

Tags: mongodb, firebase, nosql

Hello i have a datamodel like this;

```
{
  "users" : {
    "User1" : {
      "flat1" : {
        "flataddress" : "adres1",
        "flatname" : "n1"
      },
      "flat2" : {
        "flataddress" : "adress2",
        "flatname" : "n2"
      }
    },
    "user2" : {
      "flat3" : {
        "flataddress" : "a3",
        "flatname" : "n1"
      },
      "flat4" : {
        "flataddress" : "a6",
        "flatname" : "a6"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Assume that user1,user2,flat1,flat2 are some IDs formed like "3DSAZDSAPOYDZ". 
First question is how can i get all the flats which flataddress = "adres1"?

Second question is, if i need to retrieve all flats, there is IDs that cannot be guessed, If i do ref.getChild("users") the userIDs are retrieved from the snapshot like;

```
       {
  "users" : {
    "User1" : {
      "flat1" : {
        "flataddress" : "adres1",
        "flatname" : "n1"
      },
      "flat2" : {
        "flataddress" : "adress2",
        "flatname" : "n2"
      }
    },
    "user2" : {
      "flat3" : {
        "flataddress" : "a3",
        "flatname" : "n1"
      },
      "flat4" : {
        "flataddress" : "a6",
        "flatname" : "a6"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

there is user ids included already, i want something like this;

{

```
            flat1 =         {
                flataddress = adres1;
                flatname = n1;
            }
            flat2 =         {
                flataddress = adress2;
                flatname = n2;
            }


            flat3 =         {
                flataddress = a3;
                flatname = n1;
            }
            flat4 =         {
                flataddress = a6;
                flatname = a6;
            }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show code on what you have tried to do to parse this?

Comment: i can not parse code due to i do now realize what i need to write. Its a problem that if a node key is dynamic, how can i get flats which address = a3 with this model in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call your main response `jsonDict`.If you want to get into each dictionary, you would do:

```
//make an empty array to put your dictionaries in
var flatsDictArray = [[String: AnyObject]]()

//first you have to unwrap each level of the dictionary response
guard let usersDict = jsonDict["users"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
  //do something here if your json response is not what you expected
  //print usersDict below if you want to see what it looks like
  print(usersDict)
  return
}

//below we access the keys and values in the usersDict
//obj is the key, value is the value
for (obj, value) in usersDict {
  if let userFlats = value as? [String: AnyObject] {
    flatsDictArray.append(userFlats)
  }
}
```

Because of the way your JSON response is structured, flatsDictArray will have two dictionaries, each dictionary will have two keys with the JSON response listed above. So they will be sorted by flats per user.

Therefore, flatsDictArray would be:

```
["flat1": [flataddress: adres1,
           flatname: n1],
 "flat2": [flataddress: adress2,
           flatname: n2]],
["flat3": [flataddress: a3,
           flatname: n1],
 "flat4": [flataddress: a6,
           flatname = a6]]
```

So as you see, you can step through every level of dictionary to find a key or value the way I have, so if you need to find a value that equals something, you could do it the same way.

```
for(obj, value) in myLovelyDictionary {
  if value == "address1" {
  //do something
  }
}
```